# TLS Fatal: Handshake Failure

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to connect with an external service, and I have a problem with client authentication. The service requires a certificate, username and password with a request.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

I've received the PKCS#7 package with the certificates and imported:

- SSL certificate (with only public key) to LocalComputer/Personal
- Intermediate CA and Root CA to LocalComputer/TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities

I've enabled the TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 clients in the Windows Register:
[Windows Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWHWe.png)

I'm trying to connect to the server both using the WCF client and web browsers (IE and Chrome).

WCF client (.NET 4.6.1):

**App.config:**

```
<bindings>     
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator" >
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
                <clientCertificate findValue="<thumbprint>"
                           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                           storeName="My"
                           x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Program.cs:**

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
           | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
           | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

using (var client = new ServiceClient())
{
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";

    client.Open();
    var response = client.DoSth();
}
```

And I get an error:

> "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority ...".

Internet Explorer shows that:
[IE error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLvPM.png)

Chrome shows that:
[Chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqPd6.png)

I also tried to debug it via Wireshark. For me, it is suspect that the 'Certificate' message from the client doesn't contain any certificate (neither using the WCF client or a web browser). Should the certificate be added here, and if yes what could be causing a problem with it?

[Wireshark packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2v9H.png)

I know that there are a lot of articles about TLS and authentication on stackoverflow and Google, but I went through a lot of them and didn't find any info about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the `ServiceClient` is using the settings from the config file? In .Net 4.5 onwards WCF got incredibly good at pretending everything works but happily ignoring your config settings. Enable WCF Tracing and Logging to see if any config gets loaded. Do use Verbose logging.

Comment: @rene I'm able to check the client's object and I see that it contains an info loaded from the config file, so binding and clientCredentials.

I'm wondering why the web browsers are not able to reach the service or         
?wsdl info.

Answer (score 0):

We had better not specify the TLS version, configure your code to let the OS decide on.  The specific TLS version used in the communication will be determined by both the server and the client environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
Transport security mode requires that the trust relationship between the server and the client should be established before the communication.
In my opinion, the error typically indicates that the client doesn’t install the server certificate properly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
Only the server side add Servicemetadata behavior, we can access the service definition(WSDL).
Usually the client provides a certificate that is sufficient to indicate its identity and there is no need to provide a username/password again. Just like the generated client configuration, we only need to provide a certificate. How the service is specifically called, we must know the configuration of the server or the WSDL file.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: could you expand the topic about that client doesn’t install the server certificate properly? How can an install them properly or verify that? As I mentioned in the question:
> I've received the PKCS#7 package with the certificates and imported:
> SSL certificate (with only public key) to LocalComputer/Personal
> Intermediate CA and Root CA to LocalComputer/TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities. 
Should I do sth additionally? I've also check the second link and my code looks pretty the same. Only difference is that I'm using "FindByThumbprint" with certificate.

Comment: For the client certificate stored in Local Machine on the client-side, please add Everyone account to the user group who could manage the private the certificate. For the server certificate that we just have the public key, we had better install it in the local machine/RootCA.
One more thing must be noted that the client certificate should be trusted by the server. so when we provide the client certificate, we are supposed to ensure that the certificate has been installed in the server RootCA.